# Complexity of high-order differentiation

Tags: computational-complexity, computer-algebra, co.combinatorics

Let $g(x) = \exp(f(x))$. Assuming numerical (or symbolic) values of $f(x), f'(x), f''(x), \ldots, f^{(n)}(x)$ are known, is there a way to compute $g'(x), g''(x), \ldots g^{(n)}(x)$ (or even the single value $g^{(n)}(x)$) for large $n$ that is faster than explicitly generating and evaluating the expanded symbolic derivative, a polynomial which has $p(n)$ (partition function) terms?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#A_special_case

Comment: For a particular n the relevant polynomial is essentially the cycle index polynomial of S_n: http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/gila-vi-the-cycle-index-polynomials-of-the-symmetric-groups/ .  So knowing how to do this computation for arbitrary f is essentially equivalent to knowing the cycle index polynomial, which encodes a lot of information.

Comment: Thanks, this is the terminology I'm looking for. So I guess the question is: is there a better way than the naive one to evaluate this polynomial (the naive method being to generate the expanded polynomial and evaluate it term by term)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.  For example, the normal evaluation for $n=6$ requires 33 multiplications and 10 additions.  But by using an optimized straight-line program which takes care of common subexpression elimination, you can reduce that to 17 multiplications, 10 additions and 4 assignments.  For $n=8$, the reduction in multiplications goes from 84 down to 37, and at $n=12$, it goes from 397 down to 114.

Note that multiplication by constants (like $10f'(x)$) counts as a multiplication too.

You can experiment with these things by using the `codegen` package in Maple (especially the functions `codegen[optimize]` with the `tryhard` option, as well as `codegen[cost]`).  If there is interest, I can post the details of the computation here.

Unfortunately, at this point, I do not immediately see a pattern in the results, so I am not sure how to automate this and produce optimized versions directly.  But the answer to your original question is definitely 'yes'.

Comment: Excellent! This doesn't really solve the problem for arbitrary n, though.

Comment: Indeed - and I did mention that in my answer.  But I believe that at this point, you're all set for a bit of "experimental mathematics" where you stare at the results for sufficiently many n, see patterns, make conjectures, prove them, repeat.  I would even be interested in helping such a project along - I just can't lead it, I've got too many other things already on the go.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that I should post an answer, for the benefit of any potential readers from the future...

For simultaneous computation of the first $n$ derivatives, the problem is really computing the exponential of a power series, and it is a classical result that this can be done in $O(M(n))$ arithmetic operations (which most likely is optimal).

See: Brent and Kung, [Fast algorithms for manipulating formal power series](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~htk/publication/1978-jacm-brent-kung), Journal of the ACM, 1978. There are more recent papers reducing the implied constant factors.

I'm still not aware of any result to the effect that the $n$th derivative alone can be computed faster than $O(M(n))$.

Answer (score 0):

Try [automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation), which is exact but not symbolic. See also [The Arithmetic of Differentiation](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2689402) by L. B. Rall.

Comment: I don't see how AD helps here. Rather, AD of nth order requires that the symbolic nth derivatives of atomic functions are already known.